# How does quartz ensure that only one of the nodes runs the job

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, quartz

I wanted to know how does Quartz ensure that only one node in the cluster run a particular job. I know it can be done by setting some properties in quartz.properties like JobStoreTX ,etc, but what is the internal implementation that supports it?

Answer (score 1):

The Clustering in the quartz is done using the database ,so if your job store is JdbcJobStore then the clustering will happen.

Only the scheduler with the same schedule name and distinct instance_name will participate and form a cluster.

1 ClusterManager thread will be used to manage the cluster.This thread ensure that the lastcheckin time is updated at a set interval.If there is any mismatch in that set interval the instance is deemed to be down.

2 Quartz use the standardlocksemaphore for database level clustering of quartz instance

```
StdRowLockSemaphore
```

In this class quartz takes a pessimist lock on the row using the

```
select * from {}_Lock for update
```

If you check JobStoreSupport class after completing the trigger firing the row lock will be released by completing the transaction.
So if two scheduler instances will complete for the same trigger then only one will be able to succeed.

Hope this helps you in connecting the dots.